# Why am I receiving ResourceWarning when testing Flask app

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

In my Flask application which I am testing using `unittest`, when I use `send_from_directory` function in my route I am getting `ResourceWarning`.

This is the route:

```py
@app.route("/<filename>")
def file_content(filename):
    root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    data_dir = os.path.join(root, "data")
    return send_from_directory(data_dir, filename)
```

And this is the test file:

```py
def test_viewing_text_document(self):
    # with self.client.get('/history.txt') as response:
    response = self.client.get('/history.txt')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(response.content_type, "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    self.assertIn("Python 0.9.0 (initial release) is released.", response.get_data(as_text=True))
```

The exact warning is :

```bash
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py:579: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='path/history.txt'>
  if method() is not None:
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

If I use `with` statement the warning dissapears, but, I thought the `send_from_directory` function automatically handles closing of the file so my question is why do I need the `with` statement. If I just `render_template` in my route the `with` statement in the test is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The send_from_directory function in Flask does indeed handle closing the file, and you generally don't need to use a with statement explicitly. The warning you're seeing is related to the fact that the file is not being explicitly closed.

The warning is likely triggered by the way Flask handles the file streaming. Flask uses a context manager internally, and the with statement is part of that mechanism.

In your case, if you want to suppress the ResourceWarning, you can use the contextlib.suppress context manager. Here's an example:

Comment: Where is the example? ;)